# Using ngRepeat in a directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Reference this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ChTN9G) for what I have working now.

```
angular.module('app', function(){
})
.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.values = [1,2,3,4];
})
.directive('outer', function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
      items: '&'
    },
    replace: true,
    template:'<div><inner items="items()"></inner></div>',
    compile: function(){
      return function(){
      };
    }
  };
})
.directive('inner', function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
      items: '&'
    },
    replace: true,
    template:'<div ng-repeat="item in items()">{{item}}</div>',
    compile: function(){
      return function(){
      };
    }
  };
});
```

This is obviously a contrived example, but it highlights the problem.  I have an ng-repeat in a directive that is buried several levels deep.  I can pass a collection from the outer scope that makes it to the ng-repeat just fine.  However, what I would really like to do is give the consumer of the outer directive the ability to pass an ng-repeat expression (i.e, item in values track by item.ID) that can be run against the outer scope instead of the collection.

I want my inner directive to be able to take advantage of the logic built into ng-repeat to optimize rendering when the collection changes.

One option I've investigated is making new version of ng-repeat that supports directly setting the variable, collection, and track by expressions, but obviously would prefer to just leverage the existing implementation.  Other options are using $compile for every instance.  Both are doable, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way.

Comment: in directives `template` can be a function that has access to attributes if that helps. Also might want to consider `require` of outer directive controller in inner directive. Looks dangerous to me passing `items` as function...expensive in digest cycles

Comment: That may help.  The big challenge passing the expression as an attribute is having the expression evaluated against the proper scope.  Agree about items(), the plnkr is a bit simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a clean way to do this is to build the directive template based on the expression as an attribute value handled in a function.  I have a working version where you can pass the expression as an attribute on the outer directive [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/80agJ1aKGC7NRidBA4Se?p=preview).

The outer directive is clear, and easy to understand.

```
Test Directive passing expression
<outer outervalues="values" expression="(k,v) in outervalues"></outer>

<br>
Filter passed in expression to inner scope
<outer outervalues="values" expression="(k,v) in outervalues | filter:'bob'"></outer>

<br>
Filter on outer scope
<div ng-init="morevalues = ( values | filter:'bob')"></div>
<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in morevalues">
   <input ng-model="v.name">
</div>

<br>
Directive from filtered outer scope
<outer outervalues="morevalues" expression="(k,v) in outervalues"></outer>
```

With the directives as so:

```
.directive('outer', function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
      outervalues: '=outervalues'
    },
    replace: true,
    template: function (elem, attr) {
              return '<div><inner outervalues="outervalues" nestedex="' + attr.expression + '"></inner></div>';
            },
    compile: function(){
      return function(){
      };
    }
  };
})
.directive('inner', function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
      outervalues: '=outervalues'
    },
    replace: true,
    template: function (elem, attr) {
              return '<div ng-repeat="' + attr.nestedex + '"><input ng-model="v.name"></div>';
            },
    compile: function(){
      return function(){
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Hope that helps.